# Receiving "Cannot Get" error in express.js when routing to ID of an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I am creating a blog web app, where users can create articles. Once they click new article, there is a post article button which is tied to a post request which is tied to my router.post function in my JS file which contains all my routes. In this function, I am retrieving my article data (description, title, markdown, etc.). In the try section, I am saving, and then redirecting to a URL using the article ID. I have set up another route that pertains to all the id routes, in which I am attempting to display the ID of the object, but I get a cannot get error. I am wondering why I am receiving this error, as the ID is being received. The specific error is: "Cannot GET /article/5ef90e3089b93f1164842e6c". I would appreciate any assistance

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const Article = require('./../models/article')

//on articles/new, render new.ejs in articles>new
router.get('/new', (req, res)=>{
  res.render('articles/new', { article: new Article() })
})


//When you do the post request, it redirects u to /articles
router.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
  const message = "hello";
  let article = new Article({
    //record information
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    markdown: req.body.markdown
  })
  try{
      //save information, send to article/id
      article = await article.save()
      console.log(article.id)
      res.redirect(`/article/${article.id}`)


  } catch (e) {
    //rerender with preloaded data if there is an error
    res.render('articles/new', { article: article })
    console.log(e)
  }
})

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  //const article is the article with this specific id
  res.send(req.params.id)


})
```

Comment: How is this router mounted to the app? My guess is that you're missing the '/article' prefix somewhere.

Comment: @ElanHamburger -Hello, I'll try my best to reply to your question. This articles.js file, which contains all of my routes, is exported and introduced in my index.js file, where I use app.use('/articles', articleRouter), which introduces the router and sets all the routes within my articles.js file within a /article path. So what should be happening is when I press the submit button, I should be going to /articles/id but this is not working

Comment: You mentioned you are using `app.use('/articles', articleRouter)`, but the endpoint you cannot GET is `/article`, not `articles`

Comment: Mr. Hamburger, I appreciate you calling out my inconsistency that led my express server to freak out. I appreciate it! This solved it :)

Comment: @IbrahimShah Happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are mounting this to the correct point. It seems as the the error says it can't GET /article/id, but could it be that you meant /article**s**/id?

Check that the id you're are using is the proper id for what you are trying to get.

Also, your error is 'Cannot GET /article/5ef90e3089b93f1164842e6c', which doesn't include the first part of the domain (i.e. localhost or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). Did you accidentally leave that part out?

How do you attach this router (i.e. what's the code in the main file)

Also, you have 1 semicolon in your whole file, are there any runtime errors?

Perhaps, set up a get request on '/article(s)' that responds with all articles (and their id!), then verify you are using the correct id.